# Check if CURL response is empty and redirect?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to figure out how to check a `curl` response and, if it is empty, redirect to another page.

Basically, the users search for something, return the PHP `curl` response if it finds something else redirect to another page.

This is my CURL code:

```
$curl = curl_init();



curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/search/companies?q=POOP');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD,"MY-PASSWORD-GOES-HERE");
$response = curl_exec($curl);
if($errno = curl_errno($curl)) {
$error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}
curl_close($curl);

$json = json_decode($response, true);

if(!$response || strlen(trim($response)) == 0)
{
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
}
```

and I tried to do it this way:

```
if(!$response || strlen(trim($response)) == 0)
{
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
}
```

but it never redirects the page even if the results of CURL is empty.

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: You have set return transfer to false, so `curl_exec` will return true if the request succeeded. At that point `$response` is `true` and `strlen` will return 1 as `trim(true)` returns the string `1`. By that reasoning, is it that you actually want return transfer set to true to see whether the request's response was empty?

Comment: @JonStirling, i set it to true and I even removed it and still doesn't redirect to another page when its empty!

Comment: Try to `var_dump()` the response and see what's in it.

Comment: Then dump out `$response` and see what it's returning to you.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
```

to

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

This will return an empty string on failure.
You can also move

```
$json = json_decode($response, true);
```

just below the `if` condition.

If this still doesn't work, there may be some problems with your setup.
Add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and check the logs.